# Algorithm for anonymous but associated communications from a set of verified communicants?

Tags: authentication, anonymity, resources, unlinkability

Let's say that I'm selling a product, and I want to get authentic feedback from my customers. However, I have the following two constraints:

1. My customers must be able to give [at least some of] their feedback **anonymously** (and, due to practical constraints and legal reasons, it is *impossible* for I and many customers to agree on any auditor or provide *any* reasonable assurance that I "simply don't know", say, which "return envelope" I include into each box; otherwise, I'd simply pack each device with a smartcard and a video of my initializing such without observing it before sealing it in tamper-evident packaging.)
2. I must be able to associate multiple feedback entries from the same customer with *each other*; i.e. a customer **must not** be able to trick me into thinking that multiple customers share their required use-case. However, I want to be able to receive e.g. follow-ups or corrections, clarifications, etc. on feedback items with assurance that the original communicant is the one making the correction. (I additionally want to be able to track, say, particularly needy—or insightful—customers across multiple pieces of feedback.)

(It goes without saying that I must also have assurance that each piece of feedback is coming from *a* customer, not least of the reasons behind which is: this not being the case would break (2) indirectly by enabling customers to launch sybil attacks.)

Additionally, it can be assumed that customers will generally either know each other, or know *of* each other and be able to get into contact with one another; a solution *may* assume that every customer is able to get in contact with *at least a few* other customers (to verify that they have the same public key on file for me, etc.)

Is this a **solved cryptographic problem**?

- If so: what is the solution; or what algorithm, system, or class of algorithms or systems allows this?
- If not: what is the state of the art / discussion on it; or what *terminology* do cryptographers refer to this class of problems by?

Comment: Implementation detail for those considering this: given the existence of a functioning `linkable ring signature` algorithm/scheme, you could then trivially have each customer attest to you (say, during the ordering process) the public key which they wish to use for signing such anonymized feedback; you would then maintain a customer-facing directory of all such keys (does *not* need to include contact information!); encryption could be handled entirely independently as a layer on top of the signed messages.

Comment: (Any customers so wishing could then witness amongst themselves, with a blockchain, whatever, that they are all seeing the same set of keys; and could attempt to bring it to each others' or public attention if theirs was not found or they see divergent sets. May want to also sign customers' keys during order or otherwise provide a downstream validation of keys' claims to be a customer, to prevent scares from a rogue non-customer agent falsely claiming that merchant is excluding some customer keys from the directory.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing [linkable ring signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_signature). Here's a [paper from ICCSA](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11424826_65) that goes into the model and proposes some schemes.

Comment: Very nice! Though this does require customers to each have _all_ others' public "feedback handles" (`P1…Pn`), I suppose that actually does provide them some further confidence they're not being siloed by me.

Comment: Wait -- **how does this fulfill (2)**?

Comment: All ring signatures fulfill 1). Linkable signatures fulfill 2). Or have I misunderstood the requirements?

Comment: Aha, I see now that "linkability" is a _special property_ not found in all ring signature schemes. I was mistakenly reading further about the _general_ case, and noticed the second requirement wasn't fulfilled...

Comment: Another "gotcha" when looking into implementations of this: some schemes you'll find when searching for ring signature schemes are for [group signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_signature), some of which give the "group manager" the option to **deanonymize participants**, either provably by unblinding the signatures, or to themselves through the "traceability" requirement (distinct from "linkability"). Be aware of this, in any case; it may be a desired feature for some use-cases, though it breaks (1) in mine.